# nvd3 x-axis date format to use mongodb ISOdate

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, nvd3.js, angularjs-nvd3-directives

I am using Angularjs-nvd3-directives charts in my application.
The data coming from the mongodb is in the format:

[["2012-11-02T20:01:00.000Z",11],["2012-11-02T20:01:00.000Z",12],["2012-11-03T20:02:00.000Z",13],["2012-11-01T20:03:00.000Z",11],["2012-11-02T20:04:00.000Z",12],["2012-11-03T20:05:00.000Z",13]]

All the examples that I see use the Unix timestamp e.g:

[ [ 1025409600000 , 0] , [ 1028088000000 , -6.3382185140371] , [ 1030766400000 , -5.9507873460847]]

The function that works for X-axis date while using the Unix timestamp is:

```
$scope.xAxisTickFormatFunction = function() {
     return function(d) {
         return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d));
             };
         };
```

What function should I write so that I can use the iso date.
I want to display values on the X-axis for every minute

Answer (score 0):

You should return Date objects not ISO Dates to chart (because that's what it expects). Before feeding the data in your chart, you should process it

```
item.values.forEach(function (value) { //iterate over your values
  //this will transform ISO in date
  var b = value.date.split(/\D+/);
  var theDate = new Date(Date.UTC(b[0], --b[1], b[2], b[3], b[4], b[5], b[6]));
  responseObj.values.push({ //create a new array and push the new date
     x: theDate,
     y: parseInt(value.number)
  })
});
```